# Can you use the HtmlHelper.Actionlink() method to create RESTful URLs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some code like this:

```
<a href="<%= Html.ActionLink(
   e.Member.UserName,
   "profile",
   "members",
   new {username = e.Member.UserName}, null) %>"/>
```

The links it generates look like this:

> ```
> http://mywebsite.com/members/profile/?username=scottm
> ```

Is it possible to make the link this:

> http://mywebsite.com/members/profile/scottm

without having to do this:

```
<a href="members/profile/<%= e.Member.UserName %>"><%= e.Member.UserName %></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just need to set up another route.

```
routes.maproute(
    "Profiles",
    "members/profile/{UserName},
    new { controller = "Members", Action = "Profile", UserName = "" }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I also had to use HtmlHelper.RouteLink rather than ActionLink.

Answer (score 0):

I think a route like this may work. Did you try it?

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "DefaultRest",                                              // Route name
  "members/profile/{username}",                           // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Members", action = "Profile", UserName = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```